# C++/CLI: functions inherited from template class are not visible in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

I've a hard time figuring out how to make the parent class functions visible in C#.

Assume I've a template class, which defines a function foo()

```
template <int Dim, typename Type>
public ref class FixedNP
{
public:
  float foo() {return 1;};
};
```

Then I've a class which inherits from the FixedNP template:

```
public ref class Vector3fP : public FixedNP<3, float>
{
}
```

When I try to call the foo() function from the C#, eg.

```
Vector3fP bar = new Vector3fP();
bar.foo();
```

it says the function Vector3fP doesn't contain a definition for foo.

When I move the definition of foo() to the Vector3fP class, it works fine. However this is not viable in real code, because the FixedNP template contains quite a lot of functions which should be inherited from approximately 4 different classes.

After some search on the Internet I found that adding the

```
using FixedNP<3, float>::foo;
```

to the Vector3fP fixed a similar problem for someone. However in my case it just results in another error, this time when compiling the C++/CLI code:

> error C3182: 'Vector3fP' : a member using-declaration or access declaration is illegal within a managed type

Any suggestions how to make my functions visible in C#?

Comment: Templates don't have external linkage.  Not in C++ and not in C++/CLI either.  You'll have to use the *generic* keyword.  The `int Dim` won't fly. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z2kbc1y.aspx

Comment: I know it, that's one of the reasons why I inherit a "regular" class from the template.

Comment: Also I'm pretty sure I don't want generics here. First I want this to be done at compile time, second I really need the <int Dim> parameter to be int, because I use it as a template parameter later on.

Comment: Well, according to the MSDN they can be managed: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177213.aspx Moreover when trying to mix native and managed code VS will tell you.

Comment: I just found a partial solution – if I add virtual keyword to the FixedNP<>::foo() declaration, it works. Unfortunately this is of no use with static functions. That's quite a problem, because many of the functions in FixedNP template are overloaded operators…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think they key is in this claim from [Managed Templates on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177213.aspx):

> If a template is not instantiated, it’s not emitted in the metadata. If a template is instantiated, only referenced member functions will appear in metadata.

That means that functions that aren't used in the C++ code won't be in the generated DLL and you won't be able to use them from C#. To fix this, you could add a phony function to your C++ code, which references the function:

```
void phony()
{
    auto vec = gcnew Vector3fP();
    vec->foo();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped! Somehow I missed that part in documentation. I guess this will force me to create a proper testsuite.

Comment: Your answer is magic... but for some reason the function I'm trying to use is "inaccessible due to its protection level" but it's public =[

Comment: I've succeded using reflection =]

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate the whole template class without adding phony method by adding the following line.

```
template ref class FixedNP<3, float>;
```